# (Update) Suspend problem (on ubuntu studio 20. 04 LTS)

Tags: suspend, 20.04, nvidia-optimus, acpi, nvidia-prime

First of all, I apologize for the language. I'm French, but I didn't get an answer on the French forum, so I came here.

I have a problem with the sleep mode (which is quite problematic I find). When I start it, the screen goes off, but the fans start to run "full throttle"; and the light next to the ignition button stays on. Moreover, no output of this "mode"; is possible. I'm forced to reboot wildly.
I followed a documentation (French on the standby) I tried to disable the **KMS** but no effect. I've also been looking for graphics cards but nothing conclusive (I detail my configuration below). And finally I looked in many topics of the french-forum, I see that the problem is frequent but no solution seems to solve the problem on my PC.

And so, finally, I own an ASUS N55SF laptop. The battery is dead, so it has been removed, so it is plugged into the mains. I use the ubuntu studio variant (20.04 LTS) with an XFCE desktop. The kernel is therefore low latency (5.4.0-37-lowlatency x86_64). The processor is an intel 17. And finally my PC is equipped with optimus technology, with a nvidia card (GeForce GT 555M). I use PRIME and the owner driver 390.
I tried the sleep on ubuntu live USB and the ubuntu studio variant, that doesn't work either. And last thing, I didn't have that problem keeping an eye on the old version of ubuntu.

I hope that you will have ideas on how to solve this monitoring problem and I thank you in advance for your answers.

Have a nice day.

**Edit of the 25 juny :**
Hi, I kept looking for clues to this problem, and I found that the logs could be useful. But I don't know how to interpret them. So I put so below the sleep logs found in sys.log.

```
Jun 23 10:39:08 Georges dbus-daemon[1632]: [session uid=1000 pid=1632] 
Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
Jun 23 10:43:05 Georges NetworkManager[877]: <info>  [1592901785.4118] 
manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Jun 23 10:43:05 Georges NetworkManager[877]: <info>  [1592901785.4119] 
device (enp5s0): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 
'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 10:43:05 Georges whoopsie[1354]: [10:43:05] offlin
Jun 23 10:43:05 Georges NetworkManager[877]: <info>  [1592901785.4321] 
device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged 
(reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 23 10:43:05 Georges NetworkManager[877]: <info>  [1592901785.4325] 
manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Jun 23 10:43:05 Georges systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Jun 23 10:43:05 Georges systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Jun 23 10:43:05 Georges kernel: [  359.359697] PM: suspend entry 
(deep)
Jun 23 10:43:05 Georges systemd-sleep[2002]: Suspending system...
Jun 23 10:48:07 Georges systemd[1]: Starting Flush Journal to 
Persistent Storage...
```

(I put my PC to sleep at 10h43, and reboot it at 10h48).
Anyone know where the mistake came from?
Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

source:
https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend